# Running xmodmap trough systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, xmodmap

I have a script that remaps escape to caps lock. I normally call the script manually with

```
xmodmap /home/myusername/.Xmodmap;
```

.Xmodmap is a file that contains:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Escape = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

I want this command to run at boot. What I did is go to /etc/systemd/system and create a file called "startup.service" with this contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Startup Applications

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=false
ExecStart=/home/myusername/scripts/.qs

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

.qs is a script with -rwxr-xr-x permissions with contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/xmodmap /home/myusername/.Xmodmap; 
rm /home/myusername/stop_time; 
date +%D' '%T > /home/myusername/stop_time
```

I enable the command by typing systemctl enable startup (not startup.service).

Here's the funny thing. The second and third command work fine on a new boot, the first one does not. It seems to execute the command or skip it somehow. The command works fine when executed in a terminal window. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

`xmodmap` operates on a running Xserver.  It's not something you'd run at system boot; it's something you'd run after graphical login, generally as part of a user's initialization script.

Theoretically you might run it through systemd to tweak the keymap on the display manager's Xserver, using `After=display-manager.service` in your `.service` file.  This will ensure systemd doesn't run it before the graphical login is available.  This won't affect a Wayland-based display manager, any Wayland sessions, or a user session that uses a fresh Xserver process, so you probably want to rerun it during user initialization anyway.

---

(Note the XKB option `caps:swapescape` does something similar to what your `.Xmodmap` does, and will function properly in Wayland and other libinput-aware contexts that lack an Xserver for `xmodmap` to operate on.  `xmodmap` is essentially deprecated, and you should really avoid using it where possible.)

Comment: And to give a rationale *why* the proper place is to run it after graphical login: Different users may prefer different keymaps.